# NodeJS retrying POST/PUT/DELETE API, if the response time takes more than nodeJS default time

Tags: node.js, express, request

NodeJS is retrying the backend API calls if it wont get any reponse within its  default timeout(2mins). This is causing an Issue for POST/PUT/DELETE API calls, which are taking more reponse time(> 2mins). Request is going to backend multiple times from Nodejs, for one request from user.

I dont want to Increase the default timeout, as my response can vary everytime.

Please let me know if there is any configuration in nodeJs/expressJS, so that i can stop the nodeJS retry totally or customise configuration for only POST/PUT/DELETE API.

Example of how i send my request:

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let async = require('async');
let expressListRoutes = require('express-list-routes');

async.parallel([
    function () {
        //url: resource/add/
        router.post('/add', function (req, res) {

            let uiModel = req.body;
            let outputJson = Parser.parse(uiModel, 'CREATE');
            let requestPromiseModel = {
                uri: `${RESOURCES}/${uiModel.resourcePluginId}`,
                method: HttpMethod.POST,
                json: true,
                body: outputJson,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': MIMETypes.APPLICATION_JSON,
                    'Authorization': MIMETypes.TOKEN_TYPE + req.token
                },
                resolveWithFullResponse: true
            };
            rp(requestPromiseModel).then(function (results) {
                res.send(results);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                log.error(`Error: Create Resource Action: ${err}`);
                res.send(err.response);
            });
        });
    }

]);

expressListRoutes({prefix: '/resource'}, "API:", router);

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for the help In Advance :)

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you are using to send requests to the backend?

Comment: Please see my example of how am sending request to BE from nodejs

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `async.parallel` in your code is useless. You are running only one function with it so it doesn't make much sense to run one thing in parallel. Also that function doesn't call the callback provided by `async.parallel` as its first argument so `async.parallel` thinks it never finishes. And to make things worse all you do in that function is call `router.post()` which could be called directly as:

```
router.post(
    // ...
);
```

instead of:

```
async.parallel([
    function () {
        router.post(
            // ...
        );
    }
]);
```

as you do know.

The only thing that it does is that it can potentially call the `expressListRoutes({prefix: '/resource'}, "API:", router);` before the `router.post()` gets called.

Also you are using `req.body` without using `body-parser`.

And finally, here is a way to define the timeout for `request` and `request-promise` - see the docs:

- https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

> timeout - Integer containing the number of milliseconds to wait for a server to send response headers (and start the response body) before aborting the request. Note that if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option (the default in Linux can be anywhere from 20-120 seconds).

Make sure that your OS timeouts are not taking precedence here.

Comment: I have defined async.parallel bcoz i have many functions with multiple API calls... its just that i edited for the example.. Anyway thanks for your comment :)  i have a scenario something like this... if the request already reaches backend and its taking time to do some operation... In this case "How the timeout will work"?

Comment: Does it resolved the issue i have similar situation as you have mentioned